# Git: Merging child of a child branch into master

Tags: git, merge, branch

I hope this is not a duplicate. I couldn't find the answer anyways. My question: Assume we have a branch of the master called X and we create a child branch from X called Y. Now I want to merge Y directly into master. I want to know what happens to X after merging Y into master. Thanks.

Comment: Do not overthink about branches. Branches are just _pointers_ to revisions.... and git works with _revisions_. So.... it doesn't matter what branch comes form what branch. All that matters is the revisions that will be involved in an operation.

Comment: ... and X will remain where it is (pointing at that exact revision that it was pointing to before the merge).